# Where can I find price-lists for Star Trek CCG cards?

Tags: pricing, star-trek-ccg

I have some Star Trek CCG cards from the [Decipher game](http://www.wixiban.com/ccg/1e-prem.htm) in the 1990s. I'm looking to discover if any of these cards have economic value.

I've tried looking at starcitygames.com and tcgplayer.com, but neither seems to cover older CCG games. I checked ebay but people's asking prices are varied and I suspect unrealistic. I know Scrye magazine used to list prices but that's out of print.

Are there any online or paper sources for Star Trek CCG card pricelists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trollandtoad.com](http://Trollandtoad.com) has listings for all sorts of Star Trek singles.  Of course, that is the price they're selling them for, so if you're trying to sell them yourself, you're going to get a lot less than that.  They seem to be selling most cards for less than $5.  Future Enterprise is listed at $40 (and out of stock).

Answer (score 2):

Ebay is a good way to offload cards, although the "value" you get is sometimes questionable. For example, the Future Enterprise can sell for anything from £20 to £40 depending who is watching/buying, but then you might buy 1,000 cards for £12 and get 2 of them (i've recently won a bid for 1,000+ cards for £22, and the only reason I went this high is because I could see a small stack of cards which i have hardly any from that set!).

Bulk sales will sell the cards quicker, and will get more people at least watching, but you will get less in return. I have tried to sell stacks of 200 randoms starting at £2, but had no interest at all - yet a friend sold half-a-dozen 3/4 card lots for £1-2 each, simply because the buyers could see the cards.

If you know your cards, it might be worth splitting them into lots of 3/4 Rares, and start these listed at £1 or some similar value. You again will be unlikely to get their full "value" but will get more from a sizable collection than either blind-bulk sales, or holding on to them for a "rainy day" - because as people have said, they are unlikely to increase in price.

Depending what you have... I might even be interested!! :¬D

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, out of print CCG's have very little value, except if you have a lot and can find someone that wants to buy the whole collection so they can play the game with just what you provide. There is almost no market for single cards for any CCG that isn't played by a lot of people at the current time, so there's no reason for anyone to keep track of prices to sell them individually.

So, in short, no, there are no recent sources for ST:TCG card prices.

Comment: While it's certainly possible that there simply aren't recent sources for ST:CCG prices, I'm struggling to understand how there can be no market for single cards.

When you consider other collectible cards, like baseball cards, old cards have value. Thus, even if no one is playing ST:CCG, shouldn't rare or ultra-rare cards have value? Or did you mean that there's no current demand for them?

Comment: Even most old baseball cards don't have much value. Unless you are talking about cards from before 1980, only stars' cards really have value, and even then, it is only a few of their cards (mainly rookies). Sports cards are also a VERY different thing than CCG's and other collectible cards, because of that "star power".

Comment: There may be some value in ultra-rares like the "Future Enterprise" card, but even then, it is only going to be of any value to someone that wants to play the game. And if they want to play the game, at this point, they probably have EVERYTHING or want to get more than just a few single cards.

Comment: Not even die-hard Star Trek fans are really going to care about a few single cards from a CCG that's been dead for ten years.

Comment: While I have accepted your answer, please note that there's no need to yell (use all caps) in your comments. It can easily come off as snarky and impolite.

Comment: @Craig I personally take that as the market tacitly admitting that there is really almost no collector value for these things and their value is derived chiefly from desire to play the game and power level in the game :)

Answer (score 1):

www.trekcc.org maybe able to help you out, as the game is not dead as others are trying to tell you.

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere that prices are listed. Does this website provide that? And welcome to B&CG!