# Where can i sell my CCG cards?

Tags: star-trek-ccg

i have a lot of star trek 1E through to voyager, Vampire the masquerade, Shadowfist, jedi knights, rage, Battletech, alien vs predator CCG cards i'm trying to sell but have no idea where to sell them, anyone able to help me please? They're taking up space that i don't have to spare. In all it's probably around 20 to 25k cards all up....

Comment: Related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13907/how-should-i-group-rare-magic-cards-when-selling-them-online

Comment: I have found a thread  explaining where to sell magic the gathering cards but no threads on where to sell my other cards

Comment: The problem with all collectibles is you need to find a collector that would be interested in them. I would suggest Ebay.

Comment: Also related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11312/where-can-i-find-price-lists-for-star-trek-ccg-cards/12732#12732